# Separator line drag/drop tree nodes c# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, treeview

I am trying to replicate the following drag and drop functionality:[image: DefaultDragDropWindows]

However, I am having trouble drawing that black line. I end up, somehow, with three lines per node. I calculate the upper, middle and lower part of the rectangle containing the tree node and, depending on that, i draw one of the lines. If I do use treeView.Invalidate() the screens flickers too much and the line cannot be seen. I have also tried to used graphics.clear(treeView.BackColor) but it will also clear my tree nodes.

Demo:
[image: DragDrop ASE]

Code - tree events:

```
public void ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode selectedNode = (TreeNode)e.Item;
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && !selectedNode.Name.Contains("=") && !selectedNode.Name.Contains("#"))
            _treeView.DoDragDrop(selectedNode, DragDropEffects.Move);

    }

public void DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = e.AllowedEffect;
    }

public void DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!mousePoint.Equals(Cursor.Position))
            {
                mousePoint = Cursor.Position;
                bool droppable;
                TreeNode destinationNode = null;
                Point pointInTree = _treeView.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
                if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(TreeNode)))
                {
                    destinationNode = _treeView.GetNodeAt(pointInTree);
                    TreeNode souceNode = (TreeNode) e.Data.GetData(typeof(TreeNode));
                    droppable = true;
                }

                else droppable = false;

                e.Effect = droppable ? DragDropEffects.Move : DragDropEffects.None;

                Point pt = _treeView.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
                _treeView.SelectedNode = _treeView.GetNodeAt(pt);

                int dropLocation = CalculateNodeHooverArea(destinationNode, pointInTree);
                if(_dropLocation!=dropLocation)
                {
                    switch (dropLocation)
                {
                    case 0:
                        DrawLine(NodePosition.Above);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        DrawLine(NodePosition.Below);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        DrawLine(NodePosition.In);
                        break;
                }
                    _dropLocation = dropLocation;
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("TreeViewDragOverEvent: " + exception.Message);
        }
    }
public void DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Point targetPoint = _treeView.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            TreeNode targetNode = _treeView.GetNodeAt(targetPoint);
            TreeNode draggedNode = (TreeNode)e.Data.GetData(typeof(TreeNode));
            if (!draggedNode.Equals(targetNode) && !draggedNode.Nodes.Find(targetNode.Name, true).Any() &&
                targetNode.Parent != null && !targetNode.Name.Contains("=") && !targetNode.Name.Contains("#"))
            {
                int nodeLocation = CalculateNodeHooverArea(targetNode, targetPoint);

                if (e.Effect == DragDropEffects.Move)
                    draggedNode.Remove();

                switch (nodeLocation)
                {
                    case 0:
                        if (targetNode.Parent != null)
                            targetNode.Parent.Nodes.Insert(targetNode.Index, draggedNode);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        targetNode.Nodes.Add(draggedNode);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        if (targetNode.Parent != null)
                            targetNode.Parent.Nodes.Insert(targetNode.Index + 1, draggedNode);
                        break;
                }
            }
            //SaveMemento();
            _treeView.Invalidate();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(exception.Message);
        }
    }
```

The method that handles the drawing of the line:

```
    private void DrawLine(NodePosition position)
    {
        Graphics g = _treeView.CreateGraphics();
        Pen customPen = new Pen(Color.DimGray, 1) { DashStyle = DashStyle.Dash };
        if (position == NodePosition.Above)
            g.DrawLine(customPen, new Point(0, _treeView.SelectedNode.Bounds.Top),
                new Point(_treeView.Width - 4, _treeView.SelectedNode.Bounds.Top));

        else if (position == NodePosition.Below)
            g.DrawLine(customPen, new Point(0, _treeView.SelectedNode.Bounds.Bottom),
                new Point(_treeView.Width - 4, _treeView.SelectedNode.Bounds.Bottom));

        else
        {
            g.DrawLine(customPen, new Point(_treeView.SelectedNode.Bounds.X + _treeView.SelectedNode.Bounds.Width,
                _treeView.SelectedNode.Bounds.Y +_treeView.SelectedNode.Bounds.Height / 2),
                new Point(_treeView.Width - 4, _treeView.SelectedNode.Bounds.Y + _treeView.SelectedNode.Bounds.Height / 2));
        }

        customPen.Dispose();
        g.Dispose();
    }
```

Can this be solved somehow or shall I look into a different way of displaying that sort of information? (e.g. tool tip)?

Comment: Poor question. Source code missing dependant methods and variables (CalculateNodeHooverArea, mousepoint etc)

Comment: @stigzler irrelevant comment. The question is 2y old and has been marked as answered.

Comment: @stigzler Not sure how you work that out, this question is nice & comprehensive, it certainly helped me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really don't have to draw the line every time you reach near the new TreeNode. In my view, it's not a clean solution to keep using Graphics object to draw and erase something every time on drag/drop event. Instead, Here's what I call a lot more 'cleaner' way of achieving the same-

- On your Windows Form, draw a line as a static control and set its visibility to false initially. Now how do you draw a line? *Add a label control, add a solid or 3D border, clear the text, and set a fixed height - may be 2 pixels, and a width as needed*. Place this label somewhere on bottom-left corner of the form, where it doesn't come in a way of other controls on UI.
- Instead of `DrawLine` method, call it `ShowLine` or something. In this method, dynamically set the X and Y position of this new label (a line, actually) to the new location as per the position of TreeView node, and make it visible. So, every time on DragOver it would be visible on a different X and Y position, and give you the same experience as you need.
- Once the item is dropped inside a node (i.e., drag-n-drop operation is complete), set the visibility of this line label to false, and also set its X and Y position back to the original one (bottom-left corner in this case).

Comment: That is indeed a less consuming option. Will give it a shot.

Comment: Yep, it is indeed easier and I still don't know how it never crossed my mind. Thank you. Its a lot cleaner now.

Comment: how do you make the drop go through this Line control? Or clicks? I am having a little trouble making it somewhat "transparent" to click and drag... Any code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`Invalidate()` is the correct method to call when you want your control to be redrawn without performing layouting algorithms.

The problem seems to be that you use a new Graphics object by calling `_treeView.CreateGraphics()`.

You could try to just [invalidate a calculated region you want to update](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtzka3b5(v=vs.110).aspx) (where the old separator lines were drawn) <strike>or alternatively use an double-buffered approach I would rather use for fully custom drawn controls but it might be worth a try: [Remove OnPaintBackground()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32167690/704281)</strike> **update** that won't work without overriding the painting of the control in total.

As I think about that issue ... why don't you store the coords of the last line and as soon as another line gets drawn, "erase" (overpaint) it again with the same pen size and shape but with the color of the background. I know, this reads to be a bit dirty but in the end it's all about unnoticable and well performing hacks (thinking about render tricks in game engines for example). As soon as the user scrolls or does anything else that will make the overpainting unsuccessfull because the coords did change, you won't need to overpaint it either because the control as whole gets repainted by the OS.

Comment: If i were to try your first solution, I would have to have a reference to the previously accessed region, calculate it (or do this before) then invalidate it. To me, this seems like a lot of work and quite dirty. I have also tried using the OnPaint() event of the treeView component, but it is not exposed

Comment: Yeah, you do have a point when you say it like that. I will give it a try and let you know how it goes. Thank you!