# How to stop flickering when redrawing ellipses in windows forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, graphics, paint, flicker

Im trying to make a ball bouncing around on the screen, which is mostly working apart from an annoying flicker everytime it moves.

Ive been searching for a while, and most sites tell you to enable double buffering, which slightly helps but it still flickers badly.

Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this?

Thanks :)

My Code:

```
Imports System.Drawing
Public Class Form1

    Public gr As Graphics
    Public XSpeed As Integer = 2
    Public YSpeed As Integer = 2
    Public ParticleCoord(1) As Integer
    Public Blackbrush As New SolidBrush(Color.Black)



    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        gr = Me.CreateGraphics()

        YSpeed = CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 10))
        XSpeed = CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 10))

        ParticleCoord = {50, 50}

        Timer.Enabled = True

    End Sub

    Private Sub ParticleMove(ByRef XSpeed, ByRef YSpeed)
        If (ParticleCoord(0) < (12 + 1189) And ParticleCoord(0) > 12) And (ParticleCoord(1) < (12 + 449) And ParticleCoord(1) > 12) Then
            ParticleCoord = {ParticleCoord(0) + XSpeed, ParticleCoord(1) + YSpeed}
            gr.Clear(Color.White)
            gr.FillEllipse(Blackbrush, (ParticleCoord(0) + XSpeed), (ParticleCoord(1) + YSpeed), 50, 50)
        ElseIf (ParticleCoord(0) < (12 + 1189) And ParticleCoord(0) > 12) Then
            YSpeed = -YSpeed
            ParticleCoord = {ParticleCoord(0) + XSpeed, ParticleCoord(1) + YSpeed}
            gr.Clear(Color.White)
            gr.FillEllipse(Blackbrush, (ParticleCoord(0) + XSpeed), (ParticleCoord(1) + YSpeed), 50, 50)
        ElseIf (ParticleCoord(1) < (12 + 449) And ParticleCoord(1) > 12) Then
            XSpeed = -XSpeed
            ParticleCoord = {ParticleCoord(0) + XSpeed, ParticleCoord(1) + YSpeed}
            gr.Clear(Color.White)
            gr.FillEllipse(Blackbrush, (ParticleCoord(0) + XSpeed), (ParticleCoord(1) + YSpeed), 50, 50)
        Else
            YSpeed = -YSpeed
            XSpeed = -XSpeed
            ParticleCoord = {ParticleCoord(0) + XSpeed, ParticleCoord(1) + YSpeed}
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer.Tick
        ParticleMove(XSpeed, YSpeed)
    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: Never use CreateGraphics.  Use the Graphics from the Paint event of the container that is doing the drawing.  Lots of examples here to research.

Comment: Would changing this fix the lag? Thanks for the reply btw :)

Comment: Lag?  What's the timer ticking at?  WinForms isn't known for being good as a gaming platform.  It's designed more for business forms.

Comment: I mean the flickering. The timer is ticking at an interval of 1 (im assuming 1 millisecond) I was trying to create a particle collision simulator not a game. At school we have only been taught vb.net so im trying to stick with that as I know my way around it best.

Comment: I already told you.  You will only get 15 ms on that timer.  It's not a high precision timer.

Comment: Sorry I dont know if stackoverflow is messing up but I dont see your message about only getting 15ms :)

Comment: Also changing to 15ms still causes flicker

Comment: Never use CreateGraphics. Use the Graphics from the Paint event of the container that is doing the drawing. Lots of examples here to research.

Comment: Is your internet connection OK?

Comment: Your ball *flickers* because you do `gr.Clear(Color.White)` and then `gr.FillEllipse(blackBrush, ...`. Between those calls the form is painted and there is no ball. This has nothing to do with the timer frequency.

Comment: Ah right. Is there any way to fix this? because I will always have to clear the last drawn ellipse :)

Comment: Internet is fine.  You seem stuck on the timer when I keep telling you it's the CreateGraphics.  CreateGraphics is a cheat as it draws temporarily on the screen.  It ignores your buffering.

Comment: Sorry its just you posted the same thing twice I thought it was lagging... im not stuck on the timer, you asked what it was ticking at. Ill try to fix the CreateGraphics but im pretty new to painting in forms so it might take a while to figure out

Comment: It's very simple.  Put all the code that does the drawing in the `Paint` event handler and use the `Graphics` object provided.  Any time you want to redraw, e.g. on the `Tick` of a `Timer` or the `Click` of a `Button`, you call `Invalidate` on the form or another control and specify the smallest area you can that has or may have changed.  Don't just invalidate the whole form if only part of it may have changed.  You execute the entire drawing every time but it is the actual painting that is slow, so that should be kept to the minimum area possible.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the repy  How do i call ```Form1_Paint``` from ```Timer_Tick```? It throws an error when i try ```Form1_Paint()```. Thanks, Tom

Comment: Also sorry for asking seemingly obvious questions I am new to Painting / Graphics :)

Comment: Nevermind im dumb I figured it out. Thanks so much! Works perfectly :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated out in the comments, you should always use the `Graphics` object from the `Paint`-event. To invoke a redraw, call `Invalidate()` on your control. Do **not** use `Refresh()` (not that bad) or `Application.DoEvents()` (very bad) to perform redraws.

**Bonus: Pro-Tip for a very smooth drawing experience**

Get rid of `OnPaintBackground()`, see [my other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32167690/704281).

With this, you'll get good rendering performance (for GDI+), I use this a lot. You can see it over [here](https://github.com/awaescher/WinFormsCT/blob/6dca7206ca8c3b59595e14d23f7fea8496966ab0/WinFormsCT/SliceVisualizer.cs#L155) in a fun project I made to analyse WinForms control hierarchies: [WinFormsCT on GitHub](https://github.com/awaescher/WinFormsCT).

[image: WinFormsCT]

Comment: Thanks, got it working perfectly now with no flickering and minimal lag, even with 100 onscreen at once :)

Comment: Sounds good to me. WinForms and GDI+ are not that bad as many developers claim.